# bash -x /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt runs but user-data from terraform gives error

Tags: bash, jenkins, terraform, user-data

I am trying to run a script using terraform. The content of the user-data is as follows:

```
.
.
cat <<EOH | java -jar ./jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:$PASSWORD create-credentials-by-xml system::system::jenkins _
<com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey plugin="ssh-credentials@1.16">
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>$CRED_ID</id>
  <description>$SLAVE_IP pem file</description>
  <username>ec2-user</username>
  <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey\$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
    <privateKey>${worker_pem}</privateKey>
  </privateKeySource>
</com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
EOH
.
.
```

When it executes as part of user-data it gives out an error as `No such command create-credentials-by-xml`.

But when I log in to the instance and execute `bash -x /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt` it runs as expected.

Can anyone please tell what is the reason for it and how to fix it? Thanks!

I have tried #cloudhook and separating the lines as well, but didn't work.

Comment: It's almost certainly a path issue. Try using the full path to `create-credentials-by-xml`.

Comment: gave `java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:$PASSWORD create-credentials-by-xml system::system::jenkins _` still same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my question:

**Where was the problem**:
The issue was not with bash but with jenkins-cli.jar itself.

The error message showed `No such command create-credentials-by-xml` which made me think, it was bash error but in reality, it was jar file error all along.

**Reason**:
The reason it was failing at user-data execution and not at bash execution was that it was unable to load configuration of plugins in a short amount of time.

**Solution**:
From the given reason, it is obvious that it needs time so I gave it `sleep 25` to confirm it works or not and yes it does work but it was not an ideal solution.

**Optimized Solution**:
To make it better I listed the `plugins` before executing any jar commands and if the list came empty re run the commnd

```
# Creating CMD utility for jenkins-cli commands
jenkins_cmd="java -jar /opt/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:$PASSWORD"

# Waiting for Jenkins to load all plugins
while (( 1 )); do
  count=$($jenkins_cmd list-plugins 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
  ret=$?

  echo "count [$count] ret [$ret]"

  if (( $count > 0 )); then
      break
  fi

  sleep 30
done
```